# Exibir resultado de uma query numa página HTML. NODE.JS/SQL SERVER

Tags: html, sql-server, node.js

Olá,
Preciso de uma ajuda urgente.
Eu fiz uma conexão ao banco de dados sql server via node.js
Apenas para saber a quantidade de itens que tem na tabela (count).
Gostaria de mostrar esse resultado da quantidade em uma campo numa página HTML.

Até agora fiz assim, porém não funcionou.

```js
var sql = require('mssql');
const { Connection } = require('tedious');

var dbconfig = {
    server: "******", 
    user:"******",
    password:"*****",
    database:"db_pocs",
    port:1433, //default port for sql server
    options: {
        encrypt: false // if on windows azure will set to true
    }
};

function getList(){
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig);
    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("select count(ID_atividade) from atividades_func", function(err, recordset) {
            var msg = document.getElementById('num')
            if(err) throw err;
            else
                msg.innerHTML = recordset;
            conn.close(); //close connection
        });
    });
}

window.setInterval("getList()",1000)
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" onclick="nextPage('carga')">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up" style="font-size: 30px"></i>
          <p id="txt-carga">CARGA</p>
          <p class="font-weight-light" id="txt-vc">VC</p>
          <div id="num"></div>
          <p id="vc-carga"></p>
          <p class="font-weight-light" id="txt-td">TD</p>
          <p id="td-carga">25</p>
        </button>
```

Na imagem, onde tem os números (6,25,44...) preenchido a "mão", quero que ele traga essa informação direta do banco, através da select count.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei extremamente grato!